# one touch fill color in image without border

Tags: ios, uiimage, flood-fill

In Application,I used jpg image having white background and plain picture border in black color.When touch without border part it fill the color but touch on border the border is also filled thats issue.I used [this link](https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill)

Answer (score 0):

you need to know the border RGB value. So you have to check whether the touch location color is from the border's RGB or not. If not then fill the color otherwise leave as it is.

```
-(void)animator
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    int bpr =(int) CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(context);
    unsigned char * data = CGBitmapContextGetData(context);

    int randomX = arc4random()%(u_int32_t)self.frame.size.width;
        int randomY = arc4random()%(u_int32_t)self.frame.size.height;
        CGPoint myPoint=CGPointMake(randomX, randomY);

        int offset = bpr*round(myPoint.y) + 4*round(myPoint.x);
        int blue = data[offset+0];
        int green = data[offset+1];
        int red = data[offset+2];
        int alpha =  data[offset+3];

        CGFloat derivedAlpha=alpha/255.0f;

        NSLog(@"%d %d %d %d %f", alpha, red, green, blue,derivedAlpha);
}
```

Here in the randomX and randomY would be your touch location coordinate.